# Скорость получения значений и цвета ячеек Excel в Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Для работы в Python с Excel использую библиотеку openpyxl.

С помощью кода приведенного ниже считываю xlsx файл, который содержит около 100 тысяч строк.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb_n = load_workbook(filename="FULL.xlsx", read_only=True)
ws_n = wb_n["Sheet1"]
```

Потом я пытаюсь вернуть значения ячейки `ws_n['A1'].value`. 
Проблема состоит с следующем:

- Время получения значения ячейки A1 = 7 ms
- Время получения значения ячейки A100 = 136 ms
- Время получения значения ячейки A1000 = 12.4 ms

Можно заметить, что чем дальше ячейка, тем больше время получения значения и цвета ячейки. Импортировать данные через DataFrame нельзя, т.к. мне необходимо возвращать цвет ячейки.

Есть какой-нибудь способ возвращать свойства ячейки быстрее, может разумно использовать другую библиотеку?

Comment: Вам необходимо читать все столбцы или один-два? Какие действия вы планируете делать с прочитанными данными? Чем более широко описана задача тем больше вероятность получить более адекватный и подходящий для вас ответ.

Comment: Я планирую в один файл excel добавить данные по ID из другого excel файла. Что-то вроде команды ВПР в Excel. Соответствие строк я установил с помощью merge, преобразовав данные в df. Но df не хранит цвета, поэтому, после установления соответствия, я обращаюсь к excel и добавляю данные из одного в другой. Надеюсь понятно написал

Comment: Вас интересует цвет шрифта или цвет фона? Предлагаю в исходном Excel файле добавить столбец с информацией о цвете. Pandas умеет при сохранении фрейма в Excel раскрашивать ячейки по условию - [pandas style](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html)

Answer (score 1):

Можете попробовать считывать лист Excel частями с помощью библиотеки `xlrd`. Но я не уверен, что это даст требуемый результат.

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('Путь к файлу.xlsx')
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0) #лист из книги excel по индексу
#sh = wb.sheet_by_name('name') #лист из книги excel по имени

limit = sh.nrows #количество строк в листе excel

counter = 0 #счётчик

while (counter + 5000) < limit:
    for i in range(counter, counter + 5000):

        x = sh.row_values(i) #кортеж значений строки, для ячейки - sh.cell_value(row, cell)

    counter += 5000

else:
    for i in range(counter, limit):

        x = sh.row_values(i)
```

Ссылка на способ получения цветов: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991209/identifying-excel-sheet-cell-color-code-using-xlrd-package

Comment: может я ошибаюсь, но библиотека xlrd умеет работать только с xls файлами, а не с xlsx.

Comment: @Евгений, ошибаетесь) [`"xlrd is a library for reading data and formatting information from Excel files, whether they are .xls or .xlsx files."`](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

Задачу по считыванию excel файла решил следующим образом:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb_n = load_workbook(filename="FULL.xlsx", keep_links=False)
ws_n = wb_n["Sheet1"]
```

Параметр `keep_links=False` не сохраняет ссылку на внешнюю книгу, т.е. все данные загружает в "память".

Скорость получения значений ячейки сильно возросла.

1. Время получения значения ячейки A1 = 0 ms
2. Время получения значения ячейки A1000 = 0 ms
3. Время получения значения ячейки A70000 = 0.1 ms

Цена этому скорость загрузки файла функцией load_workbook, теперь данные из 10 тыс. строк импортируется около 20 минут.