# Скорость работы закраски ячеек в openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

В моем скрипте я закрашиваю несколько тысяч ячеек экселя. Использую openpyxl, функция закраски выглядит так:

```
def fill_row(sheet: Worksheet, roew: int, col_maxv int):
    for col in range(1, col_max + 1):
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).fill = Pattern fill(fgColor='000000', patternType='solid')
```

Но работает это жутко долго, судя по профилировщику, эти несколько тесяч ячеек закрашиваются около 10 секунд.

Не понимаю в чём проблема, но судя по всему, упирается все в реализацию openpyxl. Как это можно ускорить?

Comment: алгоритм простой - изучаете исходники `openpyxl`, ускоряете реализацию, делаете Git Pull Request... ;)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1091741/234134

Comment: А в `column=` там нельзя сразу список колонок указать? Может быстрее будет.

Comment: @MaxU я не настолько уверенный питонист. Я посмотрел исходники либы, но так и не понял в каком месте она тормозит.

Comment: @Violet она, к сожалению, работает только старым расширением .xls, у меня .xlsx

Comment: @CrazyElf вроде можно обращаться к списку сразу, но вот именно прописывать в fill в диапазон не получиться.

Comment: возможно ли в вашем случае использовать Google Sheet?

Comment: @Violet неа, офлайн проект. Это не настолько критичная проблема, чтобы менять либу или тип файлов. Мне просто интересно, как можно ускорить эту, как мне кажется, тривиальную задачу.

Comment: Используйте numba для ускорения.

Comment: @Александр можно попробовать, но мне кажется проблема все же в неопиисальности написанного, а не в скорости интерпретатора питона.